# Syntax error near "If" (VHDL)

Tags: if-statement, syntax, vhdl

I'm getting the following error " Line 44: "Syntax error near "If"." and something similar in lines 65, 67, 69, 73 (except with some "Else"s and other "If"s).

It's probably a very silly question, but could anyone help? :)

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

entity Four_Bit_Adder_Decimal_Output is
    Port ( A : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
           B : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
           Cin : in  STD_LOGIC;
           Res : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (4 downto 0);
           Cout : out  STD_LOGIC;
           Dsp : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
           Seg : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (6 downto 0));
end Four_Bit_Adder_Decimal_Output;  

architecture Four_Bit_Adder_Decimal_Output_Arch of Four_Bit_Adder_Decimal_Output is
    --Embedded signals
    signal Tmp : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (4 downto 0);

begin
    --Display Selection
    Dsp <= "0111";

    --Check if any of the 4-bit inputs are bigger than 9
    If ((A < 9) and (B < 9)) = '1' Then
        Tmp   <= ("00000" & A) + (B & "00000") + ("00000" & Cin);
        Res   <= Tmp;
        Cout    <= Tmp(4);
        --Output must be in decimal, so you print the first digit in the display
        seg     <= "1000000" when (Tmp = X"0") else
                   "1111001" when (Tmp = X"1") else
                   "0100100" when (Tmp = X"2") else
                   "0110000" when (Tmp = X"3") else
                   "0011001" when (Tmp = X"4") else
                   "0010010" when (Tmp = X"5") else
                   "0000010" when (Tmp = X"6") else
                   "1111000" when (Tmp = X"7") else
                   "0000000" when (Tmp = X"8") else
                   "0010000" when (Tmp = X"9") else
                   "1000000" when (Tmp = X"A") else
                   "1111001" when (Tmp = X"B") else
                   "0100100" when (Tmp = X"C") else
                   "0011001" when (Tmp = X"D") else
                   "0010010" when (Tmp = X"F");
        --Check if result has 2 digits, then turn ON Cout
        If (Tmp >= 10) Then
            Cout <= '1';
        Else
            Cout <= '0';
        End If;
    Else          -- If any of the inputs is bigger than 9, throw an error
        --Put "E" in the display
        Seg <= "0000110";
    End If;
end Four_Bit_Adder_Decimal_Output_Arch;
```

Comment: You're using a sequential statement (an If Statement) in a location appropriate for a concurrent statement.  There are other problems with your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An if-statement is always used as a sequential statement. You'd find sequential statements in places such as processes or subprograms (functions / procedures).

```
architecture Four_Bit_Adder_Decimal_Output_Arch of Four_Bit_Adder_Decimal_Output is
    ...
begin
    ...
    process(all) is begin
        if ((A < 9) and (B < 9)) = '1' then
        ...
        end if;
    end process;
end architecture Four_Bit_Adder_Decimal_Output_Arch;
```

-daniel